# How to get the active thread count?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program which calls a C++ library. The program processes has a large number of threads (50 - 60). Most of them seem to be created in C++ and I suspect most are suspended/waiting.

How do I find how many of these threads are active at a given point in time?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-thread

Answer (score 15):

To actually determine the count of **active** threads, it's necessary to check the `ThreadState` property of each thread.

```
((IEnumerable)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
    .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
    .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
    .Count();
```

Comment: Looks like you might need to check your `using`s. `IEnumerable` requires `using System.Collections`, which isn't always included by default. `OfType<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>` from `IEnumerable`. So you wouldn't need that if you're starting out with `IEnumerable<T>` like you are. On first glance, your code looks like it works the same.

Comment: This looks like java code, not c++

Answer (score 4):

You could use Process Explorer to inspect threads. It will tell you in realtime how much CPU each is consuming, and can give you individual stack traces, which will indicate what they are blocked on.