# Counting number of threads on windows server; counter path

Tags: c++, windows, pdh

There was a similar thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156474/how-can-i-programmatically-get-thread-counts-for-a-windows-process), and I tried to implement it myself. i.e. Trying to get the number of threads running in the server using c++ library.

May I know exactly what COUNTER_PATH is? (e.g. "\Process(*_)\Thread Count" in the given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156474/how-can-i-programmatically-get-thread-counts-for-a-windows-process))? What does it mean to make a string with that and the pid number?

The following is what I have wrote so far without really understanding anything:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <pdh.h> //and suppose there're other libraries as necessary...

CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = L"\Process(*)\Thread Count";

int returnNumThreads()
{
    HQUERY hQuery = NULL;
    HCOUNTER hCounter;
    DWORD counterType;
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterValue;
    PWSTR Paths = NULL;
    PDH_STATUS pdhStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);

    pdhStatus = PdhAddCounter(hQuery, COUNTER_PATH, 0, &hCounter);
    pdhStatus = PdhCollectQueryData(hQuery);
    pdhStatus = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(hCounter,
                    PDH_FMT_LONG,
                    &counterType,
                    &counterValue);
    return counterValue.longValue;
}

// **Here, I removed all the error checking codes such as 
// "if (pdhStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS){...}" for better readability
```

**Also, the solution given in the link above says to expand the wildcard path, but when I checked the [PdhAddCounter page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it said: "If the counter path contains a wildcard character, all counter names matching the wildcard character are added to the query," so I wasn't sure if expansion is really needed.

I've been looking at [various](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~mxiong/tmp/backup/RTI_Vanderbilt/throughput_internal/PerfMon.cxx) [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm not still sure if I'm creating the query correctly or still what that COUNTER_PATH is. Can anybody give me an explanation?

Comment: You probably want `PdhAddEnglishCounter`. Ì don't know what they were smoking when they dreamed up `PdhAddCounter`. Who in the world understands what `"\Proces(opera)\Piekwaarde virtuele bytes"` means??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PdhAddCounter` adds named counters to an open query. `L"\Process(*)\Thread Count"` is such a name. It's considered a "path" name as its syntax is hierarchical (parts separated by `\`), similar to file paths.

The wildcard means that you want to add the thread counters for `Process(Foo)`, `Process(Bar)`, etc to get the total number of threads for all processes together. (If you're running two copie of foo.exe, the second is `\Process(Foo#1)`

Comment: Does it mean that in order to get the number of threads specific to a process of, say pid #12, the COUNTER_PATH should be "\Process(12)\Thread Count"?

Comment: Clarified: you pass the program names.

Comment: Ah the information could be found on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780836%28v=ws.10%29, although the problem hasn't been resolved. I'll look into it..